# Conditional insert vs UNIQUE constraint

Tags: postgresql, performance, c#, postgresql-performance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069718/postgres-insert-if-does-not-exist-already

I would like to check if something exists before inserting it, what should I rely on?

`UNIQUE` constraint or `INSERT .. INTO .. WHERE NOT EXISTS ..` or maybe both? Is there any other solution?

Is it possible to check if something exists in a separate query and inserting in a separate query in the way that it's atomic? Putting it in a transaction scope maybe?

Comment: Both. Unique constraint guarantees duplicates absence ever when errorneous query executed, and WHERE NOT EXISTS prevents duplication errors during insert execution.

Comment: PS. Do not refer to previous theme. Copy the required part of the text to the new question. The question should be self-contained.

Comment: What's wrong with `insert ... on conflict do nothing` and a unique constraint?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how is that different than `where not exists`

Comment: It is faster and you don't need to deal with errors.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so it's like database's exception handling for unique constraint?

Comment: It also checks all UNIQUE (and EXCLUDE) constraints. With WHERE NOT EXISTS, you'd have to add all the conditions (one for each constraint) and modify the INSERT query when the schema (constraints) change

Comment: so how is that different than just letting it execute and handling error in code with something like `try {} catch` and using that and checking number of affected rows?

Comment: @Konrad less complexity on the one hand, and all the pros ypercube and  a_horse_with_no_name listed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are needing from the solution. If you want to 100% prevent duplicate errors you go with a constraint. If it is to minimize duplicate rows and prevent errors from happening you go with the conditional insert. If you need to prevent duplicate rows and the errors from attempting to insert a duplicate row you go with both.

If you are depending on the conditional insert you can get a duplicate row if someone is doing an insert and they do not add the condition as expected.

If you just use the constraint you will get errors that could be prevented (sometimes you want to know of the error) when attempting to insert the duplicate record.

Comment: will preventing the constraint error make any difference in performance?

Comment: @Konrad I am not sure on that but I would think it would depend on the constraint and what all needs to be checked. As for preventing the error I work with the goal of preventing them unless there is a reason you need to know of them happening.